# joining two tables with group by in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

hello i am  trying to join these two tables but am not able to.
i have the data seperately but unfortunately i cant join them as there is a group by statement involved in table nr 2 which makes the join a little bit complicated.

table nr 1; -- includes all data

```
SELECT i.attr,iv.dateofvalue,iv.price 
FROM information i, informationvalues iv
WHERE i.attr=iv.attr;
```

table nr2; -- includes only recent data excluding the price

```
SELECT i.attr, MAX (iv.dateofvalue) AS recentdate
FROM information i, informationvalues iv
 WHERE i.attr=iv.attr 
 GROUP BY i.attr;
```

The Goal is to extend tablenr 2 with its respective price by getting it from table nr 1.
NOTE: recentdate=dateofvalue 
Hope someone can help, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Who taught you those old comma-separated joins? They got replaced by explicit joins (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, etc.) more than 25 years ago! You shouldn't use them anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking to pull out the most recent price per attribute. If so, you can filter with a correlated subquery that gives you the last date per attribute:

```
select 
    i.attr,
    v.dateofvalue,
    v.price
from information i
inner join informationvalues v on v.attr = i.attr
where v.dateofvalue = (
    select max(v1.dateofvalue) from informationvalues v1 where v1.attr = v.attr
)
```